# How do I put together a function and a Polynomial with a division operator?

Tags: python, function, numpy, operator-overloading

Suppose I have the following function `g`:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P

def g(x):
    return np.log(x)
```

And I have the following NumPy Polynomial `q`:

```
q = P([0, 1])
```

I want to put them together like so:

```
fancy = g / q
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Polynomial' and 'function'
```

So that I can call `fancy(x)`, such that it's the equivalent to saying:

```
g(x) / q(x)
```

It should be trivial to just say:

```
def fancy(x):
    return g(x) / q(x)
```

But no, I need the callable function itself, because `g` gets redefined at each iteration of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
fancy = lambda x : g(x) / q(x)
```

Should give you what you want. `lambda` expressions are one way python supports creating function object on the fly. I say 'one' because you could `def` a function more than once, since it does pretty much the same thing assigning a lambda expression does, defines a function object and assigns it to a reference.

Comment: Works well, but not quite what I needed.  Instead, the new `fancy` had to be redefined based on the previous `fancy`.  This creates an infinite recursion :(

Comment: @Kit, What!? Please update your question with the failed attempt.